# Change HTTP request authorisation header with PHP or HTML

Tags: php, html, http

The **quick question** is: is there ane way to change http authorisation header with html / php / javascript?

*The goal*

I'd like to make an auth service used for user login as well as providing with whole site protection. I want user to be restricted from viewing any file except login page unless authorised. For php I can of course check at the beginning for example session token availability, and redirect if missing, but I can't do it directly for for example jpg images. I thought of creating htaccess file that will verify if user is logged.

*The solution*

1.

Using Apache I've created .htaccess file, that verifies, if HTTP authorisation is set. If not it **redirects** any request to login page. With that solution one can not open any file (no matter if it is php script or for example jpg image) except of the login page:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/login.php
RewriteRule .* /login.php [L,R]
```

2.

The login page should display form and when login and password are correct set the http request auth header with proper token.

Unfortunately I can't find a way to create manually http request auth header. The only way I found was to use basic auth:

```
$auth = new Auth();
if (!empty($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) && !empty($_SESSION)) {
    $auth->logout();
}
if (!empty($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) && empty($_SESSION)) {
    $login = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
    $haslo = (!empty($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) ? Auth::hashPassword($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) : null);
    $auth->login($login, $haslo);
}
$auth->getLoginForm();
```

Where getLoginForm() displays Basic Auth standard form

```
public function getLoginForm()
{
    header(self::HEADER_ERROR_ASK_CLIENT_DATA);
    header(self::HEADER_RESPONSE_401);
    exit;
}
```

This solution works, but http request auth header holds the original login data all the time, which is what I want to avoid. I want to inject there "Bearer + token" string, which will help in securing whole system.

*What I've tried*

1. I can easily do that with external frontend. For example with windows desktop app I can send one request with basic auth header and the next with bearer header.
2. The same I can do with JQuery and AJAX - I can retrieve token using url with basic auth, and then use token with custom header for next requests.
3. I can also make different requests with PHP CURL.

But I can't find a way to force regular browser to login with Basic auth header and after success keep new, custom bearer header for next requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard mechanism to get a User Agent (browser) to provide an `Authorization: Bearer` header by itself.

What you can do:

- make sure all your requests are done via XHR (Ajax), and send the header there. But this will not allow "regular" file loads (new pages, images, scripts, CSS...).
- what most people do: send a cookie with your authentication token, and check for that cookie. The browser will automatically send the cookie.

As an aside, note that your `.htaccess` only checks that there is an `Authorization` header present, not its value, so it's quite useless. You want to channel all reads via a script that will actually verify the header or cookie before delivering the file.

Comment: The header name is `Authorization`, not `Authorisation`.

Comment: @Pemapmodder, indeed, missed an autocorrect (using British dictionary). Fixe.

Comment: You are indeed right - htaccess in current form is useless.
I tried using auth_external to use it with PHP, but my ISP doesn't allow that.
My last idea was to leave it only as a small protection from regular users. Although simple http://login:pass@image.jpg would bypass it.
I think I am stuck with what you suggested - leave protection only to script files or route all files through script. This last option however doesn't look like the best idea.

Comment: It's obviously less efficient than having the web server deliver a static file directly, but with a minimum of optimisation (including the use of [`readfile`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)) it shouldn't be too much of an issue.

Comment: All right then, I will stick to that solution. Thanks!